# Bash on Windows while loop

Tags: windows, shell

I am attempting to port a shell script to run on GNU for Windows, which provides a bash shell for Windows. I've run into an issue:

```
while [ $no -le $number ]
```

doesn't seem to register. As a test, I tried

```
no=1
number=10
echo debug1
while [ $no -le $number ]
do
echo debug2
no=$((no+1))
done
echo debug3
```

This returns debug1 and debug3, so it doesn't seem to even enter the loop.

```
no=1
echo debug1
while [ $no -le 10 ]
do
echo debug2
no=$((no+1))
done
echo debug3
```

This, on the other hand, works, and gives me debug1, 10 debug2s, and debug3.

I'm guessing it's a syntax error, but I'm not sure how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Exactly what is "GNU for Windows"?  Do you mean MinGW?

Comment: It could be the GnuWin32 stuff. As far as I know, that provides far more than just the developmenty things from MinGW.

Comment: Oops. I meant GNU on Windows. https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki It's something like Cygwin.

Comment: @Firnagzen that is not something like Cygwin. Cygwin provides a complete Bash shell and associated Unix userspace. This only provides the GNU utilities (not the Unix shell) compiled for win32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works fine (as it should) under `bash` in Linux, and even under the relatively ancient `bash` I have in CygWin:

```
pax> number=10
pax> no=1 ; while [ $no -le $number ] ; do echo $no ; no=$((no+1)) ; done
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

My only suggestion is to print out the two variables before you attempt to enter the `while` loop, and after the `no=$((no+1))` line, in case there's something wrong, something like:

```
echo "[$no] [$number]"
```

You may also want to put a `set -x` at the top of your script as it will output each interpreted line before trying to execute it.

Comment: Accursed Heisenbugs. Disappeared when I returned home and tried it again. Maybe the GoW install needed a reboot or something.